# resizing a slickgrid column header causes it to be misaligned with body

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, slickgrid

I am using SlickGrid 2.2 with Bootstrap 3.1.0 css.  When I try to resize the column header, the column header cell is not aligned with the cell in the body.  The header is consistently larger than the body whether I am shrinking or stretching it.  I am using the code from example 1:

html

```
<div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:500px;">
```

javascript

```
 var grid;
 var columns = [{
     id: "title",
     name: "Title",
     field: "title"
 }];

 var options = {
     enableCellNavigation: true,
     enableColumnReorder: false
 };

 $(function () {
     var data = [];
         data[0] = {
             title: "Task ",
             duration: "5 days",
             percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
             start: "01/01/2009",
             finish: "01/05/2009",
             effortDriven: 10
         };

     grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
 })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stryecho/n58Cq/7/

In Bootstrap 2.3.2, the resizing seems to work as expected.

I have noticed a post about a similar issue at https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/pull/699.  There it seems to indicate that a rendering issue was fixed, however I believe my condition, where the item is resized, is still not working.

Answer (score 4):

I was solve this problem by putting slickgrid's div in div with display:table style like this:

```
<div style="display:table;">
    <div id="grid1"></div>
</div>
```

But before I found solutions:
for css:

```
[class^="slickgrid_"],
[class^="slickgrid_"] div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
     box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```

for script block:

```
grid1 = new Slick.Grid("#grid1", data, columns, options);
```

and also I use for dependency at end of code:

```
grid1.autosizeColumns();
```

Also I found that this issue is when I use

```
<center> <center>
```

tags arround div

Comment: css solution is enough for me! Thanks Kakha!

Answer (score 3):

It's most likely because bootstrap 3 uses `box-sizing: border-box`. You'll need to reset the `.slick-headers` and related slick header/column elements to use `box-sizing: content-box`

Also - the pull request you mentioned fixes the same issue but it has not been approved/merged in the actual slick grid code.

Comment: Thanks, I did try modifying the css to use content-box which does fix the issue.  However, it causes other problems where the borders do not get displayed correctly.  And from what I can tell, it looks like the fixes were applied, at least in slickgrid 2.2 (I see them in the code).  Slickgrid has code that explicitly checks for border-box and then skips the recalc of the size using padding/etc. but that does not seem to fix the error because the header column width is still off by 9 pixels from the body.

Comment: Be sure you're applying the content-box sizing to the entire grid. I had the same issues and was able to fix it with several slick selectors involved. We had to ditch bootstrap 3 due to IE7, otherwise I'd have example code I could share. I may be able to look back in our repo today and pull that out.

Comment: I've posted another question to address an issue I have if I use the box-sizing code.  You can see in that code that I am applying it to all classes that have 'slickgrid_' as per this post: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/742.  My other question (with accompanying fiddle) can be found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557847/slickgrid-cell-borders-are-clipped-after-setting-box-sizing-to-use-content-box

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I was also having issues in Firefox (only) where the header columns where misaligned with the body of the grid.  This post helped resolved my issue.  I'm using `slick.grid.css` , and as the previous post suggests. I added:

```
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
```

to:
`.slick-header-columns, .slick-headerrow-columns
   .slick-header-column.ui-state-default`

HTH