# Slickgrid cell borders are clipped after setting box-sizing to use content-box

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, slickgrid

I am using slickgrid 2.2 and bootstrap 3.1.0.  When I try to set a border around a cell, the cell below clips the border of the one above when I set the box-sizing: content-box.  The reason I seem to need that workaround (basically to fix a column width issue) is described at the end of this question.  Here is the code (using slickgrid's example 1 as the base):

css

```
[class^="slickgrid_"],
[class^="slickgrid_"] div {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}

.slick-row {
    border-right: 2px dotted #E56278 !important;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #E56278 !important;
}
```

html

```
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" width="50%">
            <div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top">
             <h2>Demonstrates:</h2>

            <ul>
                <li>basic grid with minimal configuration</li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

javascript

```
 var grid;
 var columns = [{
     id: "title",
     name: "Title",
     field: "title"
 }];

 var options = {
     enableCellNavigation: true,
     enableColumnReorder: false
 };

 $(function () {
     var data = [];
     for (i=0; i<2; i++){
         data[i] = {
             title: "Task ",
             duration: "5 days",
             percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
             start: "01/01/2009",
             finish: "01/05/2009",
             effortDriven: 10
         };
     }

     grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
 })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stryecho/LckHm/2/

As you can see, there should be a bottom border on the first cell, but it's being clipped by the one below.

Background:

In a previous question, I was trying to get to the root of the issue (I should not need to set the box-sizing explicitly since slickgrid seems to have already addressed the issue):

[resizing a slickgrid column header causes it to be misaligned with body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540490/resizing-a-slickgrid-column-header-causes-it-to-be-misaligned-with-body)

Ideally, I'd like to know if Slickgrid is already fixed and I'm just using it wrong, However, it seems as though I may need to resign myself to setting box-sizing:content-box, which now brings me to the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to your cell/row heights. Because you're now using `content-box` the row heights are `25px` *not* counting the bottom borders. The row height is actually `27px` counting the bottom border (and slick is absolutely positioning the next row 25px down...), so you'll need to force slick to limit the cell/row heights to 23px + 2px bottom border.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to avoid having to override the slickgrid css.  But setting the slick-row and slick-cell classes manually does do the trick for now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am using Slickgrid with slick.autocolumnsize plugin.
If you would like to avoid misalign in Firefox only replace the measureCellPaddingAndBorder() function in slick.grid.js to this.

I've found the answer here: https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/pull/699, but I've modified the if statements because of compatibility with Google Chrome and Firefox at the same time.
You don't have to modify the css of SlickGrid.

```
 function measureCellPaddingAndBorder() {
        var el;
        var h = ["borderLeftWidth", "borderRightWidth", "paddingLeft", "paddingRight"];
        var v = ["borderTopWidth", "borderBottomWidth", "paddingTop", "paddingBottom"];

        el = $("<div class='ui-state-default slick-header-column' style='visibility:hidden'>-</div>").appendTo($headers);
        headerColumnWidthDiff = headerColumnHeightDiff = 0;
        if (el.css("box-sizing") != "content-box" && el.css("-moz-box-sizing") != "content-box" && el.css("-webkit-box-sizing") != "border-box") {
            $.each(h, function(n, val) {
                headerColumnWidthDiff += parseFloat(el.css(val)) || 0;
            });
            $.each(v, function(n, val) {
                headerColumnHeightDiff += parseFloat(el.css(val)) || 0;
            });
        }
        el.remove();

        var r = $("<div class='slick-row' />").appendTo($canvas);
        el = $("<div class='slick-cell' id='' style='visibility:hidden'>-</div>").appendTo(r);
        cellWidthDiff = cellHeightDiff = 0;
        if (el.css("box-sizing") != "content-box" && el.css("-moz-box-sizing") != "content-box" && el.css("-webkit-box-sizing") != "border-box") {
            $.each(h, function(n, val) {
                cellWidthDiff += parseFloat(el.css(val)) || 0;
            });
            $.each(v, function(n, val) {
                cellHeightDiff += parseFloat(el.css(val)) || 0;
            });
        }
        r.remove();

        absoluteColumnMinWidth = Math.max(headerColumnWidthDiff, cellWidthDiff);
    }
```